# System crashed after creation of service: How can I reboot it?

Tags: service, crash, debian, reboot

for a lab, I was asked to created a python file that would be run as a service. After creating that file and entering the code provided, my system suddenly crashed. I tried rebooting it on multiple occasions, but it still won't work. (I will try to link images on the error message.)

Example of error message: [Failed] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization

[image]

I tried booting the system on recovery mode, but after entering my root password, it only displays this message ("Debian GNU/Linux 10 Velvet ttyl \n Velvet login: ") and I don't know what to do after. I try asking the teacher, but we couldn't figure it out either.

Comment: can you access the filesystem somehow ?

Comment: if you can access the filesystem try to move `/etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants_/systemd-timesyncd.service` (you will have to create `/etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants_` and then try to reboot again, after this setup the date corectly and link it back again